# Replicates number of repeated observations and generates a new ID that uniquely identifies observations based on a count value

Tags: r, dplyr, count, tidyr, unnest

I am trying to duplicates clusters of observations(ID) and generates a new variable that identifies the
clusters uniquely (new_ID). For instance, consider the data frame df1

```r
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3"), sex=c("M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M"),count=c(4,4,4,3,3,2))
df1
#>   ID sex count
#> 1  1   M     4
#> 2  1   M     4
#> 3  1   M     4
#> 4  2   F     3
#> 5  2   F     3
#> 6  3   M     2
```

```r
df2 <- data.frame(
 ID=c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2","3","3"),
 new_ID = c("1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","4","4","4","5","5","6","6","7","7", "8","9"),
 sex=c("M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M", "F", "F", "F", "F","F", "F","M","M"),
 count=c(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2))
df2
#>    ID new_ID sex count
#> 1   1      1   M     4
#> 2   1      1   M     4
#> 3   1      1   M     4
#> 4   1      2   M     4
#> 5   1      2   M     4
#> 6   1      2   M     4
#> 7   1      3   M     4
#> 8   1      3   M     4
#> 9   1      3   M     4
#> 10  1      4   M     4
#> 11  1      4   M     4
#> 12  1      4   M     4
#> 13  2      5   F     3
#> 14  2      5   F     3
#> 15  2      6   F     3
#> 16  2      6   F     3
#> 17  2      7   F     3
#> 18  2      7   F     3
#> 19  3      8   M     2
#> 20  3      9   M     2
```

Thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: How are clusters defined?

Comment: They are defined by ID

Comment: How do you get first 3 1's, then 3 2's etc?

Comment: The first 3 1's are obtaiined because the number of times 1 was repeated in df1 is 3. So  1's, 2's 3's and 4's in df2 are all repeated 3 times because they are all associated to ID = 1 in df1

Comment: might be me, but I'm still not getting how you calculate `df2$new_id` based in the values of `df1`...

Comment: the exact same procedure was done in stata with expandcl. https://www.stata.com/manuals13/dexpandcl.pdf

Comment: @Wimpel `ID == 1` corresponds to `count == 4`. Therefore there should be 4 clusters. `ID == 2` has `count == 2` hence 2 clusters etc. At least that's my interpretation of the data and the [expandcl manual](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/dexpandcl.pdf)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I might not be explaaining it well.  ID == 1 corresponds to count == 4, which corresponds to 4 clusters is (1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly,

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  tidyr::uncount(count, .remove  = FALSE) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(new_ID = rep(seq_len(first(count)), each = n()/first(count))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(new_ID = data.table::rleid(new_ID))


# A tibble: 20 x 4
#   ID    sex   count new_ID
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <int>
# 1 1     M         4      1
# 2 1     M         4      1
# 3 1     M         4      1
# 4 1     M         4      2
# 5 1     M         4      2
# 6 1     M         4      2
# 7 1     M         4      3
# 8 1     M         4      3
# 9 1     M         4      3
#10 1     M         4      4
#11 1     M         4      4
#12 1     M         4      4
#13 2     F         3      5
#14 2     F         3      5
#15 2     F         3      6
#16 2     F         3      6
#17 2     F         3      7
#18 2     F         3      7
#19 3     M         2      8
#20 3     M         2      9
```